# Undefined control sequence error after TeX Live update

Tags: luatex, texlive, polyglossia, cyrillic, texlive-2019

After the latest TeX Live update, I'm getting the following error while compiling my book draft with lualatex:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@begindocumenthook ...yrr \cyri \cyrl \cyro \ETC.
```

I'm not sure what might be the culprit (this is the first time I'm getting this kind of error while working on this document) or even how to track it down. Any advice would be highly appreciated. TIA.

P.S. I understand this has got to do with Russian characters or language use, and I do have some words in Russian in the text, as well as a

```
\setotherlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
```

declaration in the preamble, but these things did not cause any issues before (and the error does not go away if I remove the `\setotherlanguage` line).

P.P.S. The (almost) full preamble with an empty document body is [here](https://ghostbin.co/paste/nguce). It does reproduce the error with the latest TeX Live update.

Comment: show a small complete example, that makes it much easier to test and investigate.

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to provide a _small_ complete example since the full preamble is extensive (> 700 LoC), depends on several external files, and I have no good idea which parts of the code might be causing the error.

The preamble (minus functionality that uses proprietary Lua code and does not affect the error) is in https://ghostbin.co/paste/nguce and does reproduce the error with the latest TeX Live update.

Comment: well you at least have the preamble, we have nothing. So how do you expect us to know what's going on in your document? Copy the preamble with a small document body in a test document. If you get the error start to remove lines from the preamble until it gets a reasonable size.

Comment: You don't need an idea where the error comes from. Just reduce the document body as far as possible and then reduce the preamble as far as possible. This is best done with binary search (remove half of the document, see if the error persists, if not add the removed code back in and remove the other half, repeat). The simple example from https://gist.github.com/moewew/4d2d6cd1d27898219b184783a8818b95 works fine for me.

Comment: I uploaded the full preamble with an empty document body (see above). It does reproduce the error.

Comment: try if it works if you move the `\setmainlanguage` and `\setotherlanguage` before cleveref. And clean up your preamble, loading all this lua package (luaotfload etc) is no needed in a current system.

Comment: Thank you, that did seem to help (although I still don't understand why the error didn't occur earlier, cleveref last having been updated in 2018 (going by the documentation).

Comment: polyglossia has been updated a few days ago. I can look later what happens here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is from polyglossia and cleverref. cleverref doesn't like it if the language isn't yet declared. The following errors:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Solution: move the `\setmainlanguage{english}` before loading cleverref.